For MudCheckBox tag in v6.0.4 LabelPostion is not working
Tag is not recognizing the LabelPosition attribute, this happened when I Placed the attribute in the tag. I am unable to change the label position as it is not recognizing the attribute LabelPosition
I was trying to change the Label Position form default(End) to Start

LabelPosition for MudCheckbox is available in v6.0.15
You have to update it.
